# How deserialize nesting with various depthion with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have xml with recursive nesting:

```xml
<root>
  <groups>
    <group>
      <group_data>...group data...</group_data>
      <object>...object data...</object>
      <object>...object data...</object>
      <groups>
        <gropup>
          <group_data>...group data...</group_data>
          <object>...object data...</object>
          <groups>
            <group>
              <group_data>...group data...</group_data>
              <object>...object data...</object>
              <object>...object data...</object>
            </group>
            <group>
              <group_data>...group data...</group_data>
              <object>...object data...</object>
            </group>
          </goups>
        </group>
      </groups>
    </group>
  </groups>
</root>
```

Nesting depth can be any.

How to collect all objects with full chain groups data?

Something like this:

```java
class Item {
    private ItemData item;
}

class Group {
    private String groupData;
    private List<Group> groups;
    private List<Item> Items;
}

class ItemData {
    private String itemName;
}
```

How in Jackson annotate recursive structure?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not have a special annotation for recursive style objects. It will handle any reference, whether recursive or not.

This should do what you want: (you may need Lombok or getters, setters, default constructor)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
class Root {
    private List<Group> groups;
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "object") 
class Item {
    private ItemData item;
}

class Group {
    @JsonProperty("group_data")
    private String groupData;
   

    private List<Group> groups;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Item> items;

}

class ItemData {
    private String itemName;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in Group class. I have edited the Group.

Comment: I want map <object> to Item.class, <group> to Group.class